# I need help fix the java code required output needed the Fraction@55f96302\n is an error

Tags: java

Required output:
testing default constructor\n
\n
\n
-----------------------------\n
\n
==>Testing default constructor/toString()\n
0/1\n

My output:
testing default constructor\n
\n
\n
-----------------------------\n
\n
==>Testing default constructor/toString()\n
Fraction@55f96302\n

```
public class Fraction {

    private int num, demonator;

    public Fraction() {
        num = 0;
        demonator = 1;

    }
    public Fraction(int input) {
        num = input;
        demonator = 1;

    }
    public Fraction(int input2, int input) {
        if (num == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("num = 0");
        num = input2;
        demonator = input;

    }

    public String ToString(int i) {
        return num + "/" + demonator;

    }

    public double evaluate() {
        return num / demonator;

    }
    public boolean isImproper() {
        return (num > demonator);


    }
    public Fraction multiplyBy(Fraction another)
    {
    Fraction f = new Fraction(this.num*another.num, this.demonator*another.demonator); //you finish call to constructor
    return f;
    }

    public void invert() {
        if (num == 0)
                throw new IllegalStateException("num = 0");
        int temp = this.num; 
        num = demonator;
        demonator = temp;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have typo in your code. In Java methods are camelCase, so the method that is used in conversion is `toString`. But you implemented `ToString`. Since the language is case-sensitive it's considered different method and therefor not used. So the basic method from `object` is used. Also you should use `@override` before methods that override methods in base class and such method is `toString`.